# What bare-bones starter theme should I use given a certain layout?

Tags: magento-2.1, parent-child-theme

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. I need to create a custom theme where most pages have the layout below:

[image]

I have not done a great job at creating a **child theme** from scratch. I need an alternative. I thought of starting from a bare-bones theme (that will not be overwritten by updates).

My question is: What bare-bones starter theme should I use given the layout above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default luma theme as a starter and as you are going to create child theme; you can use Luma and customize as per your need.

As per your layout, LUMA will work best here, all you need is to add sidebar on home page.

http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/